# Time complexity of algorithm with recursion

Tags: java, data-structures, time-complexity

I have the following:

```
public static int[] MyAlgorithm(int[] A, int n) {
    boolean done = true;
    int j = 0;
    while(j <= n - 2) {
        if(A[j] > A[j+1]) {

            int temp = A[j + 1];
            A[j + 1] = A[j];
            A[j] = temp;

            done = false;
        }
        j++;
    }
    j = n - 1;
    while(j >= 1) {
        if(A[j] < A[j-1]) {
            int temp = A[j - 1];
            A[j - 1] = A[j];
            A[j] = temp;
            done = false;
        }
        j--;
    }

    if(!done)
        return MyAlgorithm(A, n);
    else 
        return A;
}
```

This essentially sorts an array 'A' of length 'n'. However, after trying to figure out what the time complexity of this algorithm, I keep running into circles. If I take a look at the first while-loop, the content in the loop will get execute 'n-2' times, thus making it O(n). The second while-loop executes in 'n-1' times, thus making it O(n), provided we've dropped the constants for both functions. Now, the recursive portion of this algorithm is what throws me off again.

The recursion looks to be tail-recursive given that it doesn't call anything else afterwards. At this point, I'm not sure if the the recursion being tail-recursive has anything to do with this time complexity... If this is really an O(n) does this necessarily mean that it's Omega(n) as well?

Please correct any of my assumptions I've made if there are any. Any hints would be great!

Comment: Your code *looks* wrong as recursion always uses the same values all the time... I'd expect one or two elements to get in they places with that code and range in recursion to be smaller (to endup with O(n^2))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is O(n<sup>2</sup>).

This is because with each recursion, you iterate the entire array twice. Once up (bubbling the highest answer to the top) and once down (bubbling the lowest answer to the bottom).

On the next iteration, you have yet another 2n. However, we know the topmost and bottommost elements are correct. Because of this we know we have n-2 unsorted elements. When it repeats, you will sort 2 more elements, and so on. if we want to find the number of iterations, "i", then we solve for n - 2i = 0. i = n/2 iterations.

n/2 iterations * 2n operations per iteration = n<sup>2</sup> operations.

EDIT: tail recursion doesn't really help with time order, but it DOES help some languages with memory processing. I can't say exactly how it works, but it significantly reduces the stack space required somehow.

Also, I'm a bit rusty on this, but O notation denotes WORST case, whereas Omega notation denotes BEST case. This is Omega(n), because the best case is that it iterates the array twice, finds everything is sorted, and doesn't recurse.

Comment: I'm some difficulty following where the n/2 iterations come from. I understand that the complexity of both loops makes it O(2n) = O(n), but it's a blur why we're diving the number of iterations by 2...

Comment: Every iteration sorts the outermost elements. There's the bottom element and the top element, resulting in "2 out of n" elements being sorted. Once an element has bubbled to the correct location, it is not touched again the way your algorithm is written. 

So each iteration sorts 2 elements in the worst case. How many iterations does it take to sort "n" elements? The answer to that question is how I get "n/2" iterations.

Comment: Ah!  So in this case, the recursive call will be called n/2 times because each pass sorts on two elements, correct?

Comment: Also, would it safe to say that recursion affects time complexities given by (#of stack frames or recursive calls)  x ( time complexity of content before recursive call) ?

Comment: No. In this case that's true because the number of steps per recursion is the same. But there are some cases where a divide and conquer algorithm may take fewer steps on each recursion. For example the first time through may take all "n" elements, but the next time through might only take half as many, and the next time even half of that. n + n/2 + n/4 + n/8 ... = 2n = O(n)

Answer (score 1):

In your case the recurrence relation is something like:

T(n) = T(n) + n.

But if we assume the biggest no. 
will end up at the end in every case. We can approximate:

**T(n) = T(n-1) +n**

T(n-1) = T(n-2) + n-1

t(n-2) = T(n-3) + n-2

T(n) = T(n-2) + n-1 +n

T(n) = T(n-3) + n-2 + n-1 + n

T(n) = T(n-k) + kn -k(k-1)/2

If n-k = 1

then k = n+1

substitutuing that

**T(n) = T(1) + n(n+1)-(n+1)(n)/2**

order O(n^2)

Also smallest no. will end up at the begining so we could also have approximated.

T(n) = T(n-2) +n

Still order would be O(n^2)

If that approximation is removed we can't estimate exactly when 
done will be true. But in this case we can be sure that the biggest no
will always end up at the end after each iteration and the smallest at the beginning so nothing would be done for 0 and n-1.

I hope this helps you understand why n^2.